# Shortcut to create PDF after selecting multiple files using single keyboard shortcut

Tags: macos

I have a lot of screenshots that I like to merge to PDF documents right from a folder. I've created a shortcut that allows me to create a PDF by using cmd-5 but I still have to right click before using cmd-5. Can someone please tell me how do I define the shortcut so I don't have to right click.

Thanks!!!

[image: Existing shortcut without right click]

Comment: Instead of a keyboard shortcut, why not create an Automator droplet and place it on your desktop or even your dock?  This way, it requires no clicks because all you have to do is drag the file(s) to the droplet

Comment: An [Automator Workflow](https://support.apple.com/guide/automator/welcome/mac)  is the same thing you created, but in a different container.

Comment: I already have too many apps on my Mac. I don't need one more. All I'm looking is for a name for right click. So it would be something like ???->Quick Actions->Create PDF. The question mark is for the right click...

Comment: Automator is built into macOS. It’s already there